# ng-pattern always shows error why?

Tags: angularjs

I have following code.

```
<input name="fname" type="text" ng-init="vprof.fname = '<?php echo $this->general["fname"]; ?>'" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"   ng-model="vprof.fname" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]$/">
<p ng-show="generalform.fname.$error.minlength && !generalform.fname.$pristine" class="help-block">Your First name should be minimum 3 character</p>
<p ng-show="generalform.fname.$error.maxlength && !generalform.fname.$pristine" class="help-block">Maximum 100 characters allowed</p>
<p ng-show="generalform.fname.$error.pattern && !generalform.fname.$pristine" class="help-block">Only Alphabets allowed</p>
```

If i type any alphabet character it shows error why?

Comment: hmmm ...  because your validation says there should be 3? This is not a proper problem description. No expected behavior given and it's really not clear what input is generating error

Comment: @Rajesh Patel Error message will be displayed when you start typing, Since ($error.minlength && ! $pristine) will be true when you enter the first character itself. as per your statement I assume that, you want to display the error message on tab out not while typing ... Use this  ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}"

Comment: myproblem is not with typing after i typed 3 alphabet character and then it also shows only alphabets allowed

Comment: Update the question to make it a proper question using proper sentences. Last comment isn't clear either

Comment: my question is simple:- i have used validation for ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]$/"   which simply means it will allows only alphabet characters.. but if i use alphabet characters then it shows error ....If anyone have problem with understanding my question simply ng-pattern for alphabeticals character is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern has the problem subtle change to that. Please change it to `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+$/"`

I have created a plnkr link for the same [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHAKAu?p=preview)